# Recuva software mixed the content of files

Tags: data-recovery, format

I'm trying to recover my folder (Java project) which contains some classes that contains Java code.I'm using Recuva software (free edition ).The problem when I recovered my files ,I found that have other format : Windows 1252 ,Does Recuva lose UTF-8 or I can find other tool to recover original format ?

My recoverd files are :

[image: Java files]
Example :
Original File:

```
..
Public class AccessToken{
...
...

}
```

Recuva recover the content like this:

[image: Recovered format ?]

Is there a tool or a way to back to UTF-8 format ?

**Edit :**

After checking each file ,I found that some files (Java classes) are recovered normally ,but some files has a content of Image files , I mean the Recuva writes Image content on Java file that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some articles about Recover softwares and how it works ,I found that it can recover data but if the files were overwritten or were changed many times ,it so difficult for Recuva to recover the original data ,so it tries recovering all versions of the same file which means you can find mixed data in the same file.

After using [Recuva](http://www.recuva.fr) ,I found that it mixed between Images files content and other types such : Java files and CSS files.

Recuva provides a good thing ,it can recover the structure of directories and the names of files.But it loses many data.

I found in [Recuva forum](https://forum.piriform.com/topic/38558-document-recovery/) the same issue which I had ,I did find the solution of kind of this issue ,but I solved the problem by using [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) and PhotoRec ,it provide a deep search to find data with low mixing but it can not recover the name of files ,so I made these steps to resolve my problem :

1-Run Recuva Wizard mode

2-Choose deep scan

3-Choose the parent directory (The project directory in my case)

4-Launch Recuva (it took 3 hours in my case)

5-Save the structure directories with undamged files(Remove overwritten files)

6-Run  TestDisk

7-Choose the necessary extensions I need (You can follow the official documentation)

8-Start the execution (it took 11 hours in my case)

9-Now,TestDisk recovers files with custom names ,but you can know the name from the content (in my case name of classes) and I made copy/paste of content to files (were recovered by Recuva sotftware) and Booooom ,every thing is well but it takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't your source code at all.

The data you're looking at is the raw data of a PNG image. (The "PNG" at the beginning of the file is a dead giveaway, along with the "IHDR" and "IDAT" strings further on.)

Comment: I just give incomplete example , I put points in source code to explain that is an example.Just to explain how the format was changed and it is not an image it is a java class but the Recuva give this result.

Comment: @XlintXms What happens when you change the extension of this particular file to `.png` and try to open?

Comment: @XlintXms So show us the results with your actual file. If you give us fake data, we can't give accurate answers.

Comment: Generally speaking, though, encoding is irrelevant to most source code -- it'll mess up some international characters, but English text and symbols will be unaffected. If you can't read the contents at all, something else is wrong.

Comment: @duskwuff ,you can see, I opened the `AccessTokenController` Java class with IDE .

Comment: @XlintXms We think it's the content of *another* file under the name of the file you want to get.

Comment: Is there another tool rather than Recuva ?

Comment: @duskwuff ,you are right the content is image  ,but the original content is java code ,because my project has images but I did not understand why it mixed the content ?

Comment: @XlintXms - Of course there is but if Recuva is doing this most file recovery software will also, the problem is how data recovery actually works, you are lucky to have recovered what you have recovered.  It does not matter what the original content was, if the data was overwritten, it's to late to recover the data.